Is there a way to recover .bak file while bypassing log files in SQL DBMI?
Can I recover the.bak file on SQL DBMI without recreating a full .bak file using this code on Azure DataBricks?
url2 = 'https:/[REDACTED]/PROD_2009_2round.bak'

# Define restore command using the credential object
restore_command = f"""
RESTORE DATABASE [PROD_2009] 
FROM URL = '{url2}';
"""

# Execute restore command
cursor.execute(restore_command)

# Close cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()

The error I'm getting is this:
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Restoring from a backup that contains multiple log files is not supported in SQL Database Managed Instance. (41921) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The workaround that ChatGPT suggest is that to create a full .bak file so that the logs will not be included. But creating a full .bak file is not an option at the moment.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-managed-instance-sql-migration-when-database-has-ganesan-k is this documnet helps you


Restoring from a backup that contains multiple log files is not supported in SQL Database Managed Instance.

Azure Database Migration Service doesn't support databases with multiple log files it is a known issue.
NO, you can't bypass transactional log .bak file. Transaction log is an integral part of the backup. If you have numerous log files, you can shrink and restructure them to create a single transaction log file. Because you cannot remote to non-empty log files, you must first back them up.
To resolve this issue, you need to first SHRINK the transactional log before you take backup from .bak file.
For more detailed information plese refer this document by @Ganeshan K.
